# Javascript redirectionament

Tags: javascript, redirect

Hi guys its m first question here y needd to check the actual url and then depending if it is ?lang=es or ?lang=en redirect to https://regular.autobusing.com/paqtur/venta?locale=es or =en clicking on a button with an id=vivesegovia

thats what ive done but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function lanzacompra(){
var URLactual = window.location.href;

document.getElementById("viveboton").onclick = function () {    
if (URLactual == "http://lasepulvedana.es/testweb/sepulvedana/vive-segovia.php?lang=en")

{   
window.location ( "https://regular.autobusing.com/paqtur/venta?empresa=lasepulvedana&locale=en");   
}

else                    
{
window.location ( "https://regular.autobusing.com/paqtur/venta?empresa=lasepulvedana&locale=es");   
}

}/*onclic*/
}/*lanzacompra*/
</script>
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance guys :)

Comment: i found the answer luckily it was just substituting window.location for window.location.replace :) hope this help someone else

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it by **assignment**, **not as parameter**

replace

```
window.location ( "https://regular.autobusing.com/paqtur/venta?empresa=lasepulvedana&locale=en");
```

by

```
window.location.href = "https://regular.autobusing.com/paqtur/venta?empresa=lasepulvedana&locale=en";
```